# How to find sides of rectangle that is inscribed in other rectangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

We have smaller rectangle inscribed in the bigger rectangle as shown on the picture.

[image: Inscribed rectangle]

The bigger outer rectangle is inclined for a certain angle. We know height and width of the bigger rectangle and we know angle of incline. Also we know that sides ratio of the both rectangles is the same.

How to find dimentions of the inner rectangle?

Comment: Do all four points of the small rectangle need to touch large one, or can it be only two of them as in the diagram? [If the latter there may be more than one answer]

Comment: Is the constraint on the small rectangle to have its sides parallel to given axes ?

Comment: cofeemath: only two points of the small rectangle should touch the bigger one
Jean Marie: the inner rectangle should be always not iclined along X and Y axes

Comment: I don't understand : you say you are looking for the **dimensions** of the inner rectangle ; but, just before, you say you know them : they are the same as the outer rectangle ?

Comment: Could you express your issue in terms of coordinates ? "I know the coordinates of ... I am looking for the coordinates of ..."

Comment: Jean Marie: I mean that with and height are dimentions (sides), but I wrote that ratios (not dimentions) of the both rectangles are the same widthbig/heightbig = widthsmall/heightsmall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a coordinate grid to the situation. The lengths of the red rectangle are $a$ and $b$, the angle is $\gamma$. I slid the blue rectangle to the left, so that it is positioned with one vertex on the origin $(0,0)$ as shown in the picture.

[image]

To calculate the dimensions of the blue rectangle, we want to find the coordinates of the point $(x_0, y_0)$. First we need to find the equation $y=mx+q$ for the line. We note that there is a rightangled triangle with $\gamma$ as an agle, such that
$$
\cos(\gamma)=\frac{b}{q}
$$
and the slope is
$$
m=\tan(\gamma) .
$$
We get
$$
y = \tan(\gamma) x + \frac{b}{\cos(\gamma)}
$$
for the line.
The point $(x_0,y_0)$ has to satisfy
$$
\frac{-x_0}{y_0} = \frac{a}{b}
$$
and as it lies on the line, we get
$$
-x_0\frac{ b}{a} = \tan(\gamma) x_0 + \frac{b}{\cos(\gamma)}. 
$$
Rearranging results in
$$
x_0 =\frac{-b}{\cos(\gamma) \left(\frac{b}{a}+\tan(\gamma) \right)}
$$
and 
$$
y_0=\frac{b^2  }{a \cos(\gamma)\left(\frac{b}{a}+\tan(\gamma)\right)}.
$$

Comment: that is amazing idea to slide the inner rectangle

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it only appears to work for a ≥ b. For the case a < b the trick seems to need an adjustment...

For completeness it would also be nice to investigate γ > pi/2...